# DocuSign: For an Angular App--why can't the OAuth redirect URL include a fragment indicator (#)?

Tags: angular, redirect, hash, docusignapi

I have a frontend app which url looks like `http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard` -> this should be also known as a redirect url when authentication is done. Unfortunately when application redirects to DocuSign login page I noticed that part of the redirect url which is after # is cut off. Is it a bug? How can I omit it?

In DocuSign panel I set redirect url as: `http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard`
My url which redirects to DocuSign to log in looks like: 
`https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id={integrator_key}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard`
The url which DocuSign construct (including redirect url) looks like: 
`https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id={integrator_key}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/piggyagent#/username` without things after `#` which ends `The provided customer ID is not registered in the DocuSign service.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Authorization Code Grant flow can only be used if the application includes a backend server which can protect the client_id's secret key. That's why the redirect URL can't include a fragment.

If you don't have a backend server then you must use the [Implicit Grant flow](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-implicit). It uses the fragment (#) part of the url to return the access token to the client (your front-end-only Angular app).

Answer (score 2):

This is not allowed per the oauth v2 specification which you can find here - https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/redirect-uri-registration/ which says "Registered redirect URLs may contain query string parameters, but must not contain anything in the fragment. The registration server should reject the request if the developer tries to register a redirect URL that contains a fragment."

You can use state to pass the information over and redirect again on the other side in your code.

Comment: State will not help me unless I am using hashes now. I would have to redesign whole application to change it. Is there any other solution for that?

Comment: I'm not sure why state will not help you. You can have a special non-Angular page that would just be used as a postback and redirect to Angular. This is not a whole redesign just a small new page and minor js

Comment: Do you have somthing more (I mean example) reagarding usage of states than it is on page with authenticating process?

Comment: I'm sorry Jan, I don't have that, but I can explain what you do. You get page.html, simple html page that has no Angular and some js in the load event. That part is simple, right? that js looks at the state parameter in the url, and creates a new url to redirect to. That would be the url you really want with the '#' stitched in between. Very simple js that you can write